# ListView form FirebaseDatabase

Tags: android, listview, firebase-realtime-database

This is my FirebaseDatabase

```
{
  "tips" : {
    "tip1" : "dfh",
    "tip2" : "dfgh",
    "tip3" : "dfghd",
    "tip4" : "dfh"
  }
}
```

I would like to populate ListView in my android aplication by values of tips( dfg,dfgh...)
How to achive it? I found movie on yt from Google Developers about Firebase UI, but there is new version of Firebase and it doesn't work like this.

Comment: so you haven't tried or researched anything and came here to ask for code.

Comment: Is it to hard for you?

Comment: help yourself and read the docs first: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Answer (score 0):

**Where device is the name of the node
and   delayTime is a integer field it limits first 70 records**

```
   final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


    Query deviceListQuery = mDatabase.child("device")
            .orderByChild("delayTime").limitToFirst(70);

    deviceListQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // Get user value

                    if (progress != null) {
                        progress.dismiss();

                    }

                    mLoadingText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Device device = child.getValue(Device.class);
                        Log.d("xxx-xxxx", "=" + device.delayTime);
                        mDeviceList.add(device);
                    }


                    if (mDeviceList.size() > 0) {
                        DeviceListAdapter deviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mDeviceList);
                        list.setAdapter(deviceListAdapter);
                    }
                    // ...
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.w("xxxxxerror", "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                    mLoadingText.setText("Error. Please try again later");
                }
            });
```